# use `sf` to plot state map (of Germany) according to variable

Tags: r, r-sf, geoplot

I'm new to geoplotting and I want to use `sf` to plot a map of Germany on the state level, with state values colored by a variable in a separate data set. How do I best go about this?

I have loaded the data and the sf object like this:

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_bw())
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)

dat <- read.table(text="
      state value
      Sachsen 10
      Bayern 30
      Rheinland-Pfalz 50
      Saarland 70
      Schleswig-Holstein 90
      Niedersachsen  100
      Nordrhein-Westfalen 80
      Baden-Württemberg 60
      Brandenburg 40
      Mecklenburg-Vorpommern 20
      Bremen 40
      Hamburg 60
      Hessen 15
      Berlin 10
      Thüringen 80
      Sachsen-Anhalt 20
", header=T)

ger_fedstates <- ne_states(country = "germany")

sp::plot(ne_states(country = "germany"))
```

How do I now color each state by the value in `dat$value`? I'm at a loss of how to best combine these two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you loaded the `tidyverse` and `sf` you can just use `left_join()`. You can use as well data from `giscoR`, that provides the names of the states in Deustch (`giscoR` source is GISCO, the Eurostat agency for spatial data), so the names can match seamlessly. Then again, use `ggplot2` (or `tmap`, `mapsf` or base `plot`) to create your plot. Key advice here is to use `sf` package instead of `sp`, since `sp` is superseeded by `sf`:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_bw())
library(giscoR)

ger_fedtstates <- gisco_get_nuts(
  nuts_level = 1,
  resolution = 10,
  country = "Germany",
  year = 2021
)



dat <- read.table(text = "
      state value
      Sachsen 10
      Bayern 30
      Rheinland-Pfalz 50
      Saarland 70
      Schleswig-Holstein 90
      Niedersachsen  100
      Nordrhein-Westfalen 80
      Baden-Württemberg 60
      Brandenburg 40
      Mecklenburg-Vorpommern 20
      Bremen 40
      Hamburg 60
      Hessen 15
      Berlin 10
      Thüringen 80
      Sachsen-Anhalt 20
", header = T)

ger_fedstates_end <- ger_fedtstates %>%
  left_join(dat, by = c("NUTS_NAME" = "state"))


# With base
plot(ger_fedstates_end["value"])
```

[image]

```r
# With ggplot2
ggplot(ger_fedstates_end) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = value))
```

[image]

```r
# With tmap
library(tmap)

tm_shape(ger_fedstates_end) +
  tm_polygons(col = "value")
```

[image]

```r
# With mapsf
library(mapsf)

mf_choro(ger_fedstates_end, var = "value")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>